# How does DeFlateStream.read redirect to System.Net.ConnectStream.Read?

Tags: c#, stream, gzipstream, deflatestream

In the process of debugging a code and it appears to me that DeFlateStream.read redirects to System.Net.ConnectStream.Read? When I check MSDN source code I couldn't easily find this redirection. Anyone could help me find how this occurs? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams aren't "redirected" - instead, DeflateStream.Read *wraps* the source stream's Read method.

That is, the wrapping DeflateStream is passed the *source* Stream (i.e. in the constructor), so that when Read is called upon it, it reads the source stream (at least insofar as it can produce valid output) and then returns the processed result from it's own Read<sup>1</sup> implementation.

Due to [Subtyping (and Inclusion Polymorphism)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), *any* object that conforms to (and is a subtype of) [IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) can be supplied as the source Stream. With respect to the DeflateStream code, this ensures that the wrapped _stream has a suitable Read method.

The *actual* stream object supplied to the constructor might be implemented as a FileStream, a MemoryStream, a ResourceStream, a ConnectedStream, etc.

See [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) and [Polymorphism in .NET - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/602141/Polymorphism-in-NET) (the section on Run-time Polymorphism) for additional details.

---

<sup>1</sup> From the [source found here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Sys/System/IO/compression/DeflateStream@cs/1305376/DeflateStream@cs), it can be seen that it amounts to:

```
public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count) {
    // Setup state

    while(true) {
        // Process buffer into result until..
        bytesRead = inflater.Inflate(array, currentOffset, remainingCount);
        if(remainingCount == 0) {
          // ..read enough, break
        }
        if (inflater.Finished()) {
          // ..or end of source stream, break
        }
        // Making sure to read more from the source stream as required
        // (_stream is a Stream, assigned in the constructor)
        int bytes = _stream.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        inflater.SetInput(buffer, 0 , bytes);
    }

    // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but the _stream is defined as System.IO.Stream and not the System.Net.ConnectedStream so I am still not quite clear how the code gets to ConnectedStream.read...

Comment: I see - so basically .NET doesn't impose a ConnectionStream here but rather the code that I am reading constructs a deflateStream object using a ConnectStream? I had thought that DeflatStream.read always calls ConnectSteam.read and that's implemented by .NET

Comment: @user2210021 Correct. .NET only requires "a Stream" is supplied, and it will work as long as the actual object passed is a conforming implementation. The "actual" Read method will be called at run-time due to subtype polymorphism (as the Read method is virtual). I've added some links.